# Loop through schemas and execute dml on the same table in each schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I have a table "active_t" in a schema called "test", having the following structure:

```
      instance      active
          IN          1
          SI          0
```

The ask is to loop through this table and for each active schema(i.e., having active=1), the code should query another table "company_t" having the following structure:

```
 code    deldate
 1234     "some date"
 9876     null
 7321     null
 9097     "some date"
```

The code needs to retrieve those company codes from company_t which have deldate as null. Once picked up, the code should further run an insert statement and insert some data in the another table "rec_t" in the test schema.

The basic code that I tried was this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
v_sql varchar2(200);
v_cntry active_t.instancename%type;
cursor c1 is
select instancename, active from active_t
where active = '1';
begin
for rec in c1
loop
execute IMMEDIATE 'select code from '||rec.instancename||'.company_t where deldate is null' into v_sql;
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
end loop;
end;
/
```

But I get an error as below:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 10
ORA-06512: at line 10
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Please help what needs to be fixed. If this simple code works then I will try to implement the insert statement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: the error is in line 10. Line 1 of the pl/sql block  is "declare", line 10 is the "execute IMMEDIATE" statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to see:
`select code from IN.company_t where deldate is null`
as the output from your code block? In which case the `execute immediate` is your problem as it is trying to run the query which is returning 2 rows to an expected single-row result.